# External Monitor Working On Linux But Not On Windows

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have an external monitor to my laptop, which runs a dual boot system.

It used to work on both Ubuntu and Windows 10, but recently and I don't know why, it stopped working on Windows, but surprisingly, it works normally on Ubuntu.

So here is what happens when I boot my PC with the monitor connected by HDMI:

If I boot into Windows the monitor does not work and is not even detected (in the device manager)
If I boot into Ubuntu the monitor is detected normally without any issues

**I have the latest kernel updates installed on Ubuntu

and also windows and the drivers for my 2 GPU's are up to date.**

How can I solve this?

Comment: If you right click the desktop and choose "Display Settings".. does it show two monitors there?  If it doesn't detect the second monitor, it won't show anything special.  Windows will usually update it's own drivers to a WHQL certified driver without going to the manufacturer's website and downloading something else.  WHQL cert will require that this is functional.  If you are looking for max frame rate.. the manufacturers website is the way to go, otherwise, this should work without a 3rd party install.  GPU ID would help here.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas it will not show the second monitor even if I press "detect" it will say `didn't detect another display`

Comment: DOUGH!  Sorry dude..